# iOS : Any Other way to put an image over a UITableView, the UITableView works normally?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

iOS : The goal is to put an image over a UITableView, the UITableView works normally.

Generally, put an image over a UITableView, the touch events of the UITableView is
cut off.

> Here is the scene, there is a piano score app. The music notes line by line is shown by a UITableView.

> Then user could put a canvas over the notes list, they could draw over the score.

> I need to put the custom drawing over the piano score UITableView, and the UITableView works normally.

**Here is my idea:**

put the drawing View on the tableView, underneath the cells.

Each cell have a reference of the drawing View.

Each cell also have a canvas slice view on its top.

The key method is `CALayer`'s `open func render(in ctx: CGContext)`

Here is the relevant code:

```
class RenderV: UIView {
    
    var renderer: UIView?
    
    var index = -1

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            else { return }
        var f: CGSize = .zero
        if let v = renderer{
            f = v.frame.size
        }
        let w = frame.size.width
        let h = frame.size.height

        context.translateBy(x: w/2 - f.width/2, y: h * CGFloat(index) - f.height)

        renderer?.layer.render(in: context)
        
    }
}
```

canvas used in UITableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
    var renderer: UIView?{
        didSet{
            guard idx > 0 else {
                return
            }
            contain.index = idx
            contain.renderer = renderer
            contain.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var contain: RenderV!
    
    var idx = -1
}
```

Call code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cel = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cel.idx = 6 - indexPath.row
        cel.renderer = img
        return cel
    }
```

***My solution is not intuitive, and needs calculating.***

***Any better idea?***

---

Here is an easy demo effect:

[image: 111]

[image: 222]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand completely what is the problem. What I understand is that the view that you render over the `UITableView` is blocking the touch events that you want to be passed to the table, right?

If it's the case, just set the view's `isUserInteractionEnabled = false`. That will enable the events to penetrate the view and be captured by the `UITableView`.